# Formatting References

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am struggling to reformat my bibliography. For the journal I am submitting to, we are allowed to use the "kluwer" document class but they require a special format for references. Currently, my references are formatted as such:

> Einstein A, Podolsky B, Rosen N, 1935. 'Can quantum-mechanical description of
>   physical reality be considered complete?'. Physical review. May
>   15;47(10):777.

but the journal I am submitting to requires:

> Einstein, Albert, Boris Podolsky, and Nathan Rosen. (1935) "Can
>   quantum-mechanical description of physical reality be considered
>   complete?." Physical review 47, no. 10 : 777.

Is there a particular reference style I could use. If not, what is the fastest and easiest way to reformat references?

Comment: If the journal does provide a class you may ask if they have a style you can use.

Comment: Yeah, one would expect that, but their answer was: "you may use the generic Kluwer Latex template, but need to have the references according to our special non-standard format"